# Why don't the galaxies collide due to gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, space-expansion, celestial-mechanics, galaxies

Why doesn't the galaxies collide due to gravitational attraction and why 
doesn't all the matter in the universe stick together due to gravitational attraction?

Comment: Galaxies do collide, but it takes forever. Read about the Big Crunch scenario for the second part.

Comment: The universe is pretty big and is expanding. Kinda hard to have everything fall back to the same point when it's moving apart faster and faster.

Comment: Related though not exactly a duplicate: [How can galaxies collide if everything moving outwards](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37907/).

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why doesn't the Moon fall onto the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/2451)

Comment: @Sam The Big Crunch is *extremely* unlikely to occur in our universe, due to the accelerating expansion of space, which slowly increases the proper distance between the galaxy clusters. But in the distant future, all the galaxies in our Local Group will most likely merge into one big elliptical galaxy.

Comment: @PM 2Ring That is why I used the word "scenario". I mentioned it because it addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxies do collide due to gravity.  They don't stick together exactly, because they're not solid bodies; but they do often merge.  See [this article](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/collision-rate.html) on the NASA website, for example.

Comment: And, of course, just because things are attracted to each other doesn’t mean they have to collide. Our solar system shows that quite well.

Comment: also, galaxies are mostly empty space. when they do collide, they do not "smash into" each other- they mostly pass right through each other, and disrupt each other's motions via gravity effects.